# How do I make JSON data persistent for offline use (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, core-data

In my app, I am currently processing a JSON file hosted on a website. I want to make it so that if a user opens the app and has no data connection, it would use the last downloaded data. I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

My original thought was to download the JSON itself, and then simply compare version numbers on load, download it if newer, and then code the app to always read the local file. However, I think I'd rather it just look at the website, store the JSON contents locally, and then upon subsequent opens, just compare the version and update its local data if the version on the site is newer.

Is there any advantage to one method over the other?

Where should I start looking for information on making the data I load from the website hosted JSON stored locally and persistent? I assume CoreData would be best for this, but my Google-fu isn't finding much on how to take JSON into Core Data.

**EDIT:**
Per Starksy's suggestion, I added the following to my app, but I'm getting an error on the `let jsonData = try ...` line.

```
func saveJSONFile() {
    let itemName = "myJSONFromWeb"
    let hostedJSONFile = "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json"
    do {
        let directory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
        let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(itemName)
        // let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(hostedJSONFile.self, from: Data)
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: hostedJSONFile, options: .mutableContainers)
        try jsonData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
        //Save the location of your JSON file to UserDefaults
        defaults.set(fileURL, forKey: "pathForJSON")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The error is

> Ambiguous reference to member 'jsonObject(with:options:)'

When I google that, I see another SO post that says I should use `JSONDecoder().decode` instead since I'm using Swift 4, but I'm not sure how to convert the above code to use that method instead.

Comment: CoreData is maybe a bit much, that would be when you want a database to manipulate objects. 
It's possible that cacheing the http response is enough, see [urlCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcache). It would otherwise be simple to save the json string to UserDefaults.

Comment: There are a few options: if you literally only want to save the JSON string, you could save it as a utf8 string to User Defaults. You could use the `codable` protocol to decode it to an object and store that with NSCoding or Core Data etc. I’d recommend saving it locally by some means then checking for a new version and updating the UI if one is available.

Comment: @quin Agreed - Core Data is likely overkill for this scenario.

Comment: I also intend on saving an image hosted on the same site when the user visits the appropriate bonus (it's the image they have to match). Additionally, the user can take pictures and save them to each bonus. Not sure if that changes the thoughts here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at Realm if you ever need local storage. It is an alternative to Core Data, but is simpler to use:
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

For this task specifically, I wouldn't save to CoreData or Realm, but directly to the app directory, and save the version and location of the file in the UserDefaults.

1) (UPDATED ANSWER)

```
//Download the file from web and save it to the local directory on the device
let hostedJSONFile = "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json"
let jsonURL = URL(string: hostedJSONFile)
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let itemName = "myJSONFromWeb"
do {
    let directory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(itemName)
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL!)
    try jsonData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
    //Save the location of your JSON file to UserDefaults
    defaults.set(fileURL, forKey: "pathForJSON")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

2) Save the version of your JSON (if it has a version coming from the web) to UserDefaults:

```
defaults.set(1, forKey: "jsonVersion")
```

3) When you launch your app, you want to verify the current jsonVersion to the version you saved in document directory:

```
let currentVersion = //...get the current version from your JSON file from web.
let existingVersion = defaults.integer(forKey: "jsonVersion")
if currentVersion != existingVersion {
   //Download the newest JSON and save it again to documents directory for future use. Also, use it now for your needs.
} else {
   //Retrieve the existing JSON from documents directory
   let fileUrl = defaults.url(forKey: "pathForJSON")
   do {
       let jsonData2 = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl!, options: [])
       let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData2, options: .mutableContainers)
       //...do thing with you JSON file
       print("My JSON: ", myJson)
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
```

Comment: This seems logical enough. I also plan to save an image once the user taps on a specific bonus (also pulled form the website) and then the user can take pics and they should be saved as well. Does that information change the above, or would I just treat the images the same as the JSON File and save it locally?

Comment: I tried that and on the line `let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: hostedJSONFile, options: .mutableContainers)` I am getting the error: Ambiguous reference to member 'jsonObject(with:options:)'. I searched for that and found some references saying I should do this with `codable` and `JSONDecoder()` instead, but I'm not clear on how to properly do the `from: Data` portion if I do it that way (I am using Swift 4). Another suggestion was to import Foundation, which I did, but it didn't resolve it. You'll note I renamed jsonData to hostedJSONFile as well (including the let).

Comment: This is a bit OT for the OP, but I think this question illustrates the point that CG needs to be replaced by something modern. Apple's purchase of their online graph engine suggests a reasonable solution is an embedded version that works with it.

Comment: An actual snippet of your code would help a lot. It's difficult to troubleshoot without seeing where you might make the error. Please post your code, and I will try to help.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please be so kind and give credit for it. Thanks

Comment: @Starsky My apologies, I was out of town. I have edited the original question to include my code and the details of my issue.

Comment: Well, your hostedJSONFile isn't a JSON, but just a String. You need to download data from the URL described in the String, then you will have a JSON file :) I will update my answer to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much @Starsky, that was a huge help. I made a new question to address my current issue as I wanted to include multiple code snippets. You can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942306/reading-local-json-file-and-using-it-to-populate-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

its not the best answer but what you can do is save it in user defaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "jsonData")
```

do not save the object, just the data that you get from your session, then make a prase method

```
func parseJSON (dataRecieved : Data) -> [ItemsJSON] {
    var jsonArray = [ItemsJSON]()
    do {
    let decode = JSONDecoder()
    let json = try decode.decode(CustomJSONClass.self, from: dataRecieved)
        if json.error == true {
            print("error from server")
        }
        for index in json.data {
            jsonArray.append(index)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("error in appending json")
    }
    return jsonArray
}
```