# Reading local JSON file and using it to populate UITableView

Tags: json, swift

I am writing an app that needs to look at a local JSON file, then compare it's version to one I have hosted on a website. If they don't match, download the one from the web and save it locally. If they do match, then continue on and use the local JSON file. This version info is in the JSON file itself.

Previously, my app would simply parse the online data and use that directly. It would then populate the UITableView using the JSON data. Now that I am using my local file, the UITableView isn't getting populating, and I'm not certain how to fix it. From reading the new function, I think my issue is that I'm not using JSONDecoder(), and instead using JSONSerialization(), and therefore I can't point it at the specific metadata I want.

26 Jun 18 Edit (Below is my BonusListViewController.swift file):

```
//
//  BonusListViewController.swift
//  Tour of Honor
//
//  Created by Tommy Craft on 6/6/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Tommy Craft. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import os.log
import Foundation

class BonusListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var bonuses = [JsonFile.JsonBonuses]()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // MARK: Data Structures
        // Settings Struct
        struct Constants {
            struct RiderData {
                let riderNumToH = "riderNumToH"
                let pillionNumToH = "pillionNumToH"
            }
            struct RallyData {
                let emailDestinationToH = "emailDestinationToH"
            }
        }

        //MARK: Check for updated JSON file
        checkJSON()

        //MARK: Trigger JSON Download
        /*
        downloadJSON {
            print("downloadJSON Method Called")
        }
        */
    }
    // MARK: - Table View Configuration
    // MARK: Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("Found \(bonuses.count) sections.")
        return bonuses.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Found \(bonuses.count) rows in section.")
        return bonuses.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = bonuses[indexPath.section].name.capitalized
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
    }
    // MARK: - Table View Header
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return bonuses[section].state
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 3
    }

    // MARK: Functions
    // MARK: - Download JSON from ToH webserver

    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFile.self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                    print("Downloading Updated JSON (Version \(posts.meta.version))")
                    print(posts.bonuses.map {$0.bonusCode})
                    print(posts.bonuses.map {$0.state})
                    self?.bonuses = posts.bonuses
                    self?.defaults.set("downloadJSON", forKey: "jsonVersion") //Set version of JSON for comparison later
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //reload table in the main queue
                        self?.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Download Failed")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }


    func checkJSON() {
        //MARK: Check for updated JSON file
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let hostedJSONFile = "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json"
        let jsonURL = URL(string: hostedJSONFile)
        var hostedJSONVersion = ""
        let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: jsonURL!)
        let jsonFile = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]
        let metaData = jsonFile["meta"] as! [String : Any]
        hostedJSONVersion = metaData["version"] as! String
        let localJSONVersion = defaults.string(forKey: "jsonVersion")
        if localJSONVersion != hostedJSONVersion {
            print("L:\(localJSONVersion!) / H:\(hostedJSONVersion)")
            print("Version Mismatch: Retrieving lastest JSON from server.")
            updateJSONFile()
        } else {
            //Retrieve the existing JSON from documents directory
            print("L:\(localJSONVersion!) / H:\(hostedJSONVersion)")
            print("Version Match: Using local file.")
            let fileURL = defaults.url(forKey: "pathForJSON")
            do {
                let localJSONFileData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL!, options: [])
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: localJSONFileData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]
                //Use my downloaded JSON file to do stuff
                print(myJson)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //reload table in the main queue
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func updateJSONFile() {
        print("updateJSONFile Method Called")
        let hostedJSONFile = "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json"
        let jsonURL = URL(string: hostedJSONFile)
        let itemName = "BonusData.json"
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        do {
            let directory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
            let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(itemName)
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL!)
            let jsonFile = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : Any]
            let metaData = jsonFile!["meta"] as! [String : Any]
            let jsonVersion = metaData["version"]
            print("JSON VERSION ", jsonVersion!)
            try jsonData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
            defaults.set(fileURL, forKey: "pathForJSON") //Save the location of your JSON file to UserDefaults
            defaults.set(jsonVersion, forKey: "jsonVersion") //Save the version of your JSON file to UserDefaults
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //reload table in the main queue
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? BonusDetailViewController {
            destination.bonus = bonuses[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the JsonFile.swift:

```
import Foundation

struct JsonFile: Codable {
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let fileName: String
        let version: String
    }
    struct JsonBonuses: Codable {
        let bonusCode: String
        let category: String
        let name: String
        let value: Int
        let city: String
        let state: String
        let flavor: String
        let imageName: String
    }
    let meta: Meta
    let bonuses: [JsonBonuses]
}
```

Is this related to not using JSONDecoder() in my updated version or am I going down the wrong path there? Also, how do I get this new data to work with the UITableView?

Comment: `myJson` is of type `Any`. You can't access `bonuses` on something of type `Any`.

Comment: I'm guessing it is Any because I didn't declare it as something else, but not sure what I need to call it to make it work.

Comment: @rmaddy If I may ask, why change the tag from swift4 to swift? Most anything I have found that is Swift 1 or 2 simply doesn't work, and even the swift 3 answers tend to have to be modified.I'm only using Swift 4 (as far as I know anyway) and from simplicity would prefer answers in Swift 4 form.

Comment: `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` only returns a dictionary or an array. Cast it (safely) as needed. But it can never be an instance of your custom class/struct.

Comment: This is approx. your 10th question about very similar things. Didn't you learn anything from the previous answers for example how to use `JSONDecoder`??

Comment: @vadian Well, it still doesn't quite work right (the UITableView is still blank), so I haven't learned enough yet, though I am trying. This particular question here stemmed from me trying to use the local file only, rather than looking directly at the hosted one (which is what I think you helped me with previously). But admittedly no, I still don't fully understand it. I'm asking similar questions in different ways trying to better understand it, hoping one of them will "click" for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are parsing JSON values incorrectly. You need to first understand your JSON format. You go to your JSON file link, and analyze it. If it starts with a "{", then it is a Dictionary, if it starts with a "[", then it is an Array. In your case, it is a Dictionary, then there come the keys which are Strings ("meta", "bonuses"). So, we know our keys are Strings. Next, we look at our values. For "meta" we have a Dictionary of String : String; for "bonuses" we have an Array of Dictionaries.
So, our JSON format is [String : Any], or it can be written `Dictionary<String, Any>`.

Next step, is accessing those values in the Dictionary.

```
func updateJSONFile() {
        print("updateJSONFile Method Called")
        let hostedJSONFile = "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json"
        let jsonURL = URL(string: hostedJSONFile)
        let itemName = "BonusData.json"
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        do {
            let directory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
            let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(itemName)
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL!)
            let jsonFile = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : Any]
            let metaData = jsonFile!["meta"] as! [String : Any]
            let jsonVersion = metaData["version"]
            print("JSON VERSION ", jsonVersion!)
            try jsonData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
            defaults.set(fileURL, forKey: "pathForJSON") //Save the location of your JSON file to UserDefaults
            defaults.set(jsonVersion, forKey: "jsonVersion") //Save the version of your JSON file to UserDefaults
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //reload table in the main queue
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Then, when you access your locally saved file, again, you have to parse the JSON to check the versions:

```
func checkJSON() {
        //MARK: Check for updated JSON file
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let hostedJSONFile = "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json"
        let jsonURL = URL(string: hostedJSONFile)
        var hostedJSONVersion = ""
        let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: jsonURL!)
        let jsonFile = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]
        let metaData = jsonFile["meta"] as! [String : Any]
        hostedJSONVersion = metaData["version"] as! String
        let localJSONVersion = defaults.string(forKey: "jsonVersion")
        if localJSONVersion != hostedJSONVersion {
            print("\(localJSONVersion) : \(hostedJSONVersion)")
            updateJSONFile()
        } else {
            //Retrieve the existing JSON from documents directory
            print("\(localJSONVersion) : \(hostedJSONVersion)")
            print("Local JSON is still the latest version")
            let fileUrl = defaults.url(forKey: "pathForJSON")
            do {
                let localJSONFileData = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl!, options: [])
                let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: localJSONFileData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]
                //Use my downloaded JSON file to do stuff

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //reload table in the main queue
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to allow arbitrary loads in your Info.plist file, because your JSON file is hosted on a website without https.
[image: Allow Arbitrary Loads]

Comment: I feel I understand what is going on in the code you posted, but I'm having problems getting it to populate the UITableView. I have a line at the beginning of my app: `var bonuses = [JsonFile.JsonBonuses]()`, and then in the old method, I had `let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFile.self, from: data!)`. Now that was pulling directly from the website, which I don't want. So in the new code, I think `myJson` contains the same data as my old `posts` did, but I'm not sure how to say that in the app. All my tableView stuff looks at that `bonuses` var though, so that must be my issue.

Comment: JsonFile references my JsonFile.swift file which contains the struct that matches the JSON structure.

Comment: I can't say where the problem is, because I don't see your "cellForRow at" method which populates your tableView, also I don't see your struct, to understand what you're doing there. The answer above answers the first part of your question, but I don't know what happens when you call tableView.reloadData(). Post your entire viewController including tableView delegate methods.

Comment: I have modified the original question to include the entire viewController and struct.