# How to save multi images from URLs to local storage in swift?

Tags: swift, userdefaults, network-connection

I am developing Restaurant app.
There are 340 foods data.
I am getting this data from backend that developed with Laravel.
App is working well in online.
But, although network is turned off, All foods data should be displayed in app.
So, I tried to save foods data to local.
It is good to save text data to local(exactly, UserDefaults and FileSystem).
But, when I try to save images to local from urls, It occur error and don't save to local exactly.

Have you ever seen such problems?
If yes, I appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Nobody has seen a single line of code.  What does "There are 340 foods data" mean?  340 records?  What does each record represent?  In what form?  In JSON?

Comment: Hi there, please read this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. Then put some code so we can help you with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what error you faced, but I think the answer to the link can help you.

- [How do I make JSON data persistent for offline use (Swift 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790702/how-do-i-make-json-data-persistent-for-offline-use-swift-4/50792836)

Additionally, image data would be good to be cached.
If you communicate based on `URLSession`, you can process caching as below.

- Saving an Image to a Cache

  `Cache.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)`
- Bring up cached images

  `let cacheImage = Cache.imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)`

***Code***

```
class Cache {
   static let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
}


extension UIImageView {
  func imageDownload(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    if let cacheImage = Cache.imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
            self?.contentMode = mode
            self?.image = cacheImage
        }
    }
    else {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else {
                    print("Download image fail : \(url)")
                    return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                print("Download image success \(url)")

                Cache.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)

                self?.contentMode = mode
                self?.image = image
            }
         }.resume()
      }
   }
}
```

To make caching more convenient, use a library called `Kingfisher`.

- [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage lazy loadings, you can use [SDWebImages](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) instead of manage it manually

SDWebImages will automatically manage your images caches and will also load them without internet here is a simple usage of it

add pod in podfile

```
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

**usagae:**

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```